# putting a scroller around a border container

Tags: apache-flex, scroll, containers, flex4.5

I have a border container component that has some other components. the problem is when the other components inside the border components are called, the spread out of the border. Does anyone know how i could add scrollers round the border such that itz components are just within it?

```
<s:BorderContainer id="varGroup" includeIn="initial">
    <s:Form width="151" height="154">
        <s:layout>
            <s:FormLayout gap="0" />
        </s:layout>
        <s:FormItem width="137" label="Name:" height="25">
            <s:TextInput id="TnameTI" width="99"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem width="137" label="condition:" height="25">
            <s:TextInput id="TcondTI" width="99"/>
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
    <components:NewModel x="0" y="61"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<s:BorderContainer id="varGroup" includeIn="initial">
<s:Scroller left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
<s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:Form width="151" height="154">
        <s:layout>
            <s:FormLayout gap="0" />
        </s:layout>
        <s:FormItem width="137" label="Name:" height="25">
            <s:TextInput id="TnameTI" width="99"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem width="137" label="condition:" height="25">
            <s:TextInput id="TcondTI" width="99"/>
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
    <components:NewModel x="0" y="61"/>
</s:Group>
</s:Scroller>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Comment: I did tried that and got this error message:  
    'Multiple initializer values for default property, 'viewport', of   type 'spark.core.IViewport'

Comment: Ok, I've edited my post with very obvious fix described in error message :)

Comment: i would give it to Constantiner since he started it all but thanks @Chris. you also did a good job

Comment: @henry no problem what so ever :) we are here to help each other ;)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a s:Group inside a s:Scroller

This should do it:

```
<s:BorderContainer id="varGroup" includeIn="initial">
    <s:Scroller left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
        <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
            <!-- your stuff goes here -->
        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:BorderContainer>
```